# Calling Stored Procedure using Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, stored-procedures

I want to know whether it is possible to call stored procedure using Spring Data JPA which is having resultset and multiple out parameter.

I found Git issue for same https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/issues/80

If it is resolved, could someone provide one example with Spring Boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've accomplished this in the past is to add custom behavior to a Spring Data JPA repository ([link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour)). Inside that I get the EntityManager and use java.sql.Connection and CallableStatement

Edit: Adding high level sample code. Sample makes the assumption that you are using Hibernate but idea should be applicable to others as well

Assuming you have an EntityRepository

```
public interface EntityRepositoryCustom {

    Result storedProcCall(Input input);
}

public class EntityRepositoryImpl implements EntityRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Result storedProcCall(Input input) {
        final Result result = new Result();
        Session session = getSession();
        // instead of anonymous class you could move this out to a private static class that implement org.hibernate.jdbc.Work
        session.doWork(new Work() {

            @Override
            public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                CallableStatement cs = null;
                try {
                    cs = connection.prepareCall("{call some_stored_proc(?, ?, ?, ?)}");
                    cs.setString(1, "");
                    cs.setString(2, "");
                    cs.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR); 
                    cs.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR); 
                    cs.execute();

                    // get value from output params and set fields on return object
                    result.setSomeField1(cs.getString(3));
                    result.setSomeField2(cs.getString(4));
                    cs.close();

                } finally {
                    // close cs
                }
            }
        });
        return result;
    }

    private Session getSession() {
        // get session from entitymanager. Assuming hibernate
        return em.unwrap(org.hibernate.Session.class);
    }

}
```